# Send pipeline input by name to a non-matching property name

Tags: powershell

I have a function which creates an object which has a property name of 'Incident Number':

```
Function Get-ID {
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{'Incident Number' = 'INC12345'; 'Other Stuff' = 'Blah'}
}
```

I want to send that 'Incident Number' value in to another function via the pipeline, but in the second function the input property is named 'ID':

```
Function Get-Note {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$ID
    )
    Write-Output "The input was $ID"
}
```

While it is possible to have a variable name with spaces (e.g `${Incident Number}`) this then makes it awkward to use as a parameter at the command-line.

As defined above, the output is:

```
The input was @{Other Stuff=Blah; Incident Number=INC12345}
```

Using `[Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName)]` returns:

> Get-Note : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the
>   command either because the command does not take pipeline input or 
>   the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that
>   take pipeline input.

FYI - The above is an example. In reality the properties of the object that is created by the first function are determined by an API call. While I could rename these properties as part of this function, my preference is to keep them as defined by the API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered that it is possible to do this by using the `[Alias()]` parameter attribute:

```
Function Get-ID {
    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{'Incident Number' = 'INC12345'; 'Other Stuff' = 'Blah'}
}

Function Get-Note {
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('Incident Number')]
        [string]$ID
    )
    Write-Output "The input was $ID"
}
```

Output:

> PS > Get-ID | Get-Note
>
> The input was INC12345